# Kubernetes fission create env error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-fission

I've installed the fission CLI with

```
curl -Lo fission https://github.com/fission/fission/releases/download/v0.2.1/fission-cli-osx && chmod +x fission && sudo mv fission /usr/local/bin/
```

Now I wan to create nodejs environment

```
fission env create --name nodejs --image fission/node-env:v0.2.1
```

but i returns an error

```
/usr/local/bin/fission: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

what should I do?

Comment: What OS/arch are you using?

Answer (score 2):

There are two versions of fission available one for Linux and one for Mac OS X, see here: http://fission.io/docs/0.3.0/install/

It looks like you have downloaded fission CLI for OSX and using it on Linux. See here: http://fission.io/docs/0.3.0/install/#linux